# Ordering a GROUP BY query

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 database in my very simple program written in python. Table I have a problem with contains three columns:

```
id, software_version, place
```

Now I would like to count the frequency of a particular software version, so I created this query:

```
SELECT software_ssh, COUNT (software_ssh)  FROM simple_table group by software_ssh
```

As a result I have got:

```
program_version_1.1, 2
program_version_1.2, 2
program_version_1.3, 20
program_version_2.1, 7
```

Unfortunately the output is not sorted by frequency. How can I fix the query to make it work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ORDER BY` on the `COUNT` results; give that result an alias:

```
SELECT
    software_ssh,
    COUNT (software_ssh) as freq
FROM simple_table
GROUP BY software_ssh 
ORDER BY freq
```

Use `ORDER BY freq DESC` if you need the rows ordered from most frequent to least.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> c.execute('SELECT software_ssh, COUNT (software_ssh)  FROM simple_table group by software_ssh')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x102034490>
>>> pprint(list(c))
[(u'program_version_1.1', 2),
 (u'program_version_1.2', 2),
 (u'program_version_1.3', 20),
 (u'program_version_2.1', 7)]
>>> c.execute('''
... SELECT
...     software_ssh,
...     COUNT (software_ssh) as freq
... FROM simple_table
... GROUP BY software_ssh
... ORDER BY freq
... ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x102034490>
>>> pprint(list(c))
[(u'program_version_1.1', 2),
 (u'program_version_1.2', 2),
 (u'program_version_2.1', 7),
 (u'program_version_1.3', 20)]
```